# NGINX DNS resolve issue

Tags: nginx, dns

I configured nginx as a load balancer and as long as the IP of the nginx server is called everything runs perfect. But the proxypass is not working.

Here is the crucial config part:

```
upstream discover {

    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server <ipOfAppInstance01>:80;
    server <ipOfAppInstance02>:80;

}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

location /discover/ {
        proxy_pass http://discover;    <---upstream group name

}
```

In some cases the configured proxypass path ("discover/discover/...") is called instead of the nginx server IP ("10.55.22.13/discover/...) and thats when I get the DNS resolve error. Did I get the config wrong? Or is that a DNS server issue, instead of nginx?

Regards
A

Comment: Can you edit and include a log file from `nginx`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I only get a "unable to resolve server's DNS address" in my webapp, no nginx errors are thrown, but just the usual access logs.

Comment: seems to be a DNS issue, try `dig` on the same host and see how the name resolves or not

Comment: I did a nslookup and "discover" can't be resolved. To be honest I thought with the proxy_pass configuration the "discover" will lead to the localhost hostname/IP being called in the end and not "discover/discover". Can this be changed in the nginx configuration or  do I need the "discover" to be added to the DNS settings? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with this topic...

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to test some more, but I think I solved this in the nginx configuration by doing something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://main;
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```